# How to iterate through an array in order to query a particular key in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of numbers.  I'd like to compare each item in the array to all the values for a particular key of a collection.  Is that possible? In the example below, I'd grab only those objects that have an id of 05,07,21,36,and 42.. but this attempt fails -

```
var playlist =[05,07,21,36,42]
```

The query:

```
Track.find({ id: playlist })...
```

The collection:

```
artist:{type: String}, 
title: {type: String},
id: {type: String}...
```

The property is actually "_id" -- Track.find({ "_id": {$in: playlist} }) -- and when I tried this, I was returned the error printed below.   Any ideas?

message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723427,597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723429,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342c,597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723429,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342c,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342b,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342d" at path "_id" for model "Track"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723427,597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723429,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342c,597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723429,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342c,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342b,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342d"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723427,597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723429,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342c,597e2f68c83f5d5ba6723429,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342c,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342b,597e2f68c83f5d5ba672342d',
  path: '_id',

Comment: All MongoDB documents **always** have an `_id` field present which "by default" is an `ObjectId` and not a "string". Mongoose "aliases" this property by default as `id`, so the problem here is that Mongoose does not understand you meant to "override" this property and is attempting to "cast" to the `ObjectId` type, and the data is invalid for that type. If you intend to "override" then you need to tell the schema that with `{ "_id": false }` as an option. i.e `Schema({ artist: String, title: String, _id: String },{ _id: false })`. Then mongoose knows to use the defined `String` instead.

Comment: That would be valid for `var playlist =[05,07,21,36,42]` as you define in your question. But the **actual error message** suggests that in fact you are sending a "string of comma delimited values". So instead you would [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the "string" to an array. `.find({ "_id": { "$in": playlist.split(/,/) } })` and of course **do not** then define `id: String` in the schema since the values are in fact of `ObjectId` type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $in. Try `Track.find({ id: { $in: playlist } })`

See [Mongo $in Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)